# TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

Tags: python, unicode

New to python....Trying to get the parser to decode properly into a sqlite database but it just won't work :(

```
# coding: utf8
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from string import *


conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# # create a table
def createTable():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE characters
                      (rank INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT, definition TEXT) 
                   """)


def insertChar(rank,word,definition):
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO characters (rank,word,definition)
                        VALUES (?,?,?)""",(rank,word,definition))


def main():
    createTable()

    # u = unicode("辣", "utf-8")

    # insertChar(1,u,"123123123")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.zein.se/patrick/3000char.html').read())
    # print (html_doc.prettify())   

    tables = soup.blockquote.table

    # print tables

    rows = tables.find_all('tr')
    result=[]
    for tr in rows:
        cols = tr.find_all('td')
        character = []
        x = cols[0].string 
        y = cols[1].string 
        z = cols[2].string 
        xx = unicode(x, "utf-8")
        yy = unicode(y , "utf-8")
        zz = unicode(z , "utf-8")
        insertChar(xx,yy,zz)

    conn.commit() 

main()
```

I keep getting the follow error: 
`TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

```
WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 48, in main
    xx = unicode(x, "utf-8")


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 52, in <module>
main()
File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 48, in main
insertChar(x,y,z)
File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 20, in insertChar
VALUES (?,?,?)""",(rank,word,definition))
pysqlite2.dbapi2.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch
```

I'm probably doing something thats really stupid... :( Please tell me what I'm doing wrong... Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhh, unicode. The bane of every python devel- hang on, why are you using `unicode()`? use `u"博人"` and do it the pythonic way.

Comment: @Hiroto are you proposing to replace code with literals?

Comment: @wRAR I meant the commented out parts for insertion. The `unicode()` calls in the code itself are redundant and throw errors anyway

Comment: @Hiroto They are commented out and so are not related to the question.

Comment: @wRAR They are in the body of the code, so it's a fair (and often obvious) assumption that the OP is using that code elsewhere. Hence why it's a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x` is already `unicode`, as the `cols[0].string` field contains `unicode` (just as [documented](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)).

Comment: okay.... so I used the x instead of xx now... I'm getting a `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 48, in main
    insertChar(x,y,z)
  File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 20, in insertChar
    VALUES (?,?,?)""",(rank,word,definition))` Why is that?

Comment: @user805981 is that the full message?

Comment: @user805981 I don't see the actual exception text.

Comment: sorry about that its here

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 52, in <module>
main()
File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 48, in main
insertChar(x,y,z)
File "sqlitetestbed.py", line 20, in insertChar
VALUES (?,?,?)""",(rank,word,definition))
pysqlite2.dbapi2.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch`

Comment: The `rank` column is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and you are inserting a string.

Comment: it is supposed to be a number... so instead of using `x = cols[0].string` i used `x = cols[0].integer` ... it passes though the parser and seems like it should have inserted into the db, but when I opened up the db file, it is empty. :/

Comment: @user805981 Where did you get that `.integer` field? I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: I think I'm supposed to do an int(cols[0].string) ... got cha.. .. So when I use bs4, the first tr line or row is all words, and I won't be able to change that into any numbers, how do I skip that?

Comment: @user805981 how is it related to this question?